# Enabling SSL on Flask + Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, https, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to implement some Google APIs in my Flask/Google App Engine web app.

I'm currently stuck on the authentication part as oauth2 redirect URI requires the connection to be secure and I cannot do that with Flask since it's the GAE environment that starts my flask app and I cannot do as suggested from the Flask documentation [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/111/)

Do you know how to enforce HTTPS on a Flask application ran by Google App Engine?

Comment: Which of the environments are you on? Standard or flexible?

Comment: In addition to flexible or standard, are you using a custom domain or the provided appspot.com domain?

Comment: Standard Env, appspot domain

Comment: see suggestion below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Justin's answer which works well for app engine apps on the flexible runtime, it might be 'simpler' to just use the `secure` option or attribute on your url handler in your `app.yaml` file since you're running in standard.

For example:

```
- url: .*
  script: main.app  # the flask app handling requests
  secure: always
```

This will force all requests to use https on the appspot domain.

Note that if you decide to add a custom domain later, you'll need to provide valid https certificates yourself to handle https properly

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. But the problem now is that I can't test it in the dev environment as said [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_secure) the secure connection is ignored in the development web server. Any Idea how to do that? It's becoming extemely painful to debug the next steps in the authentication process

Comment: You shouldn't have issues in the dev environment. The redirect uri works fine with localhost too.  http://imgur.com/YZ6p0aQ

Comment: If I use localhost this is the message i'm getting when hitting the redirect URI on localhost:8080 :
**Sorry, unexpected error: (insecure_transport) OAuth 2 MUST utilize https.**

Comment: you might be doing something wrong then: should usually be `http://localhost:8080` https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#creatingcred

Comment: I don't know why but now localhost it works as you pointed. probably I just needed to review my code

Comment: awesome, glad it's fine for you now :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a library that forces redirects based on the x-forwarded-proto header.  Take a look at this:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman